# iOS App Extension - Is there any chance to identify the host app when the extension runs?

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm developing an app extension on iOS 8. And it has some special feature that can only work on a specific host app. Therefore I need to identify the host app when my extension runs so that I can determine whether to enable that feature. Is there any API to do so? Like get the app id of the host app?

Comment: What type of extension are you developing?

Comment: A keyboard extension.

Comment: Your app could write a file to your shared container when your app comes to the foreground and then delete it when your app moves to the background.  Your keyboard would then check for the presence of this file and enable your 'special' features if it is found.

Comment: I think what your method is to check the containing app, not the hosting app. "An app that contains one or more extensions is called a containing app. An app that a user employs to choose an app extension is called a host app." It's easy to mix up with these two concept.

Comment: My method would detect if the host app was the containing app.

Comment: OK. But I want to detect the host apps. Like if it's iMessage, or it's Safari. Any way to do that?

Comment: I am looking for same thing. Anybody found out?